# .Htaccess redirect breaks file path

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I'm attempting to canonicalization my URL. However, when adding the relevant code, it breaks my other rewrite rules which allows me to hide the .html/ .php. It works fine when landing on the homepage but when you go to a page with www. and a file path at the end of the URL the page redirects to the homepage without www.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.bespoke-apertures\.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://bespoke-apertures.co.uk/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Difficult to understand the problem. What URL is not working and what is the error? Did you test from a new browser?

Comment: @anubhava the website domain is https://bespoke-apertures.co.uk. When adding www. It now redirects removing the www. but now adds /public_html

Comment: @anubhava Through testing it turns out $1 is passing through the /public_html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it like this in different order:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(bespoke-apertures\.co.uk)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Make sure to test this in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Thank you! It also turned out that my file was in the incorrect folder, but all fixed now thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to redirect without www :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I've copied your replaced my line 5and6 with your code, however this hasn't seemed to effect anything,

Comment: This has now stopped all links from working as it constantly redirects to /public_html